# Is this a well known space? Perhaps homogeneous Sobolev-like space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces, schwartz-distributions

The homogeneous Sobolev space $\dot H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is often defined as the closure of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ under the norm

$$ || |\omega|^s \widehat{f}  ||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)} =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\omega|^{2s} ||\widehat{f}(\omega)|^2 d \omega$$

I am asking about the following space: Take a non-zero vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Denote by $D_v f$ the derivative of $f$ in the direction of $v$:

$$D_v f = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}   $$

where $v = (v_1, \dots v_n)$. The space I want to know about is the closure of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ under the following norm:

$$||D_v f ||_{L^2(\mathbb{R^n})} $$

or equivalently on the Fourier domain, it's the closure of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ under the norm:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\langle v, \omega \rangle|^2 |\widehat{f}(\omega)|^2 d \omega $$

This space contains $\dot H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ since for any $ f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\langle v, \omega \rangle|^2 |\widehat{f}(\omega)|^2 d \omega  \leq ||v||^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} ||\omega||^2 |\widehat{f}(\omega)|^2 d \omega
\end{equation}

It looks similar $\dot H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but is clearly not. Is this space known or is there a "standard" way to think about it?

Comment: are you also looking for some particular estimate?

Comment: @ThomasKojar Not necessarily. I just want to know if the space is equivalent to a well-known space. An estimate may shed light on that question.

Comment: It's clearly not $H^1$ since (if $v=e_1$, say) there are $L^2$ functions for which $xf(x,y)\in L^2$, $yf(x,y)\notin L^2$.

Comment: Probably about all one can say is the tautological: it's the space of $L^2$ functions with directional derivative $D_v f\in L^2$ also.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I am not convinced that the space is a subspace of $L^2$.

Comment: And while we are at it, the "norm" isn't even a norm.

Comment: The natural way to salvage something would be to take the sum of the $L^2$ norm and the above seminorm. You wouldn't get the space you want but a mixed space, representable as a Hilbert space tensor product of an $L^2$-space and a Sobolev one.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I am also not convinced that this is a subspace of $L^2$.

Comment: @terceira Unsure why you say it's not a norm.

Comment: @WillieWong: Yes, it's the weighted space $L^2(\mathbb R^2, x^2\, dxdy)$ after taking FT, which indeed (obviously) contains functions not in $L^2$ (and functions not in $L^2((x^2+y^2)\, dxdy)$), I didn't read the OP carefully enough.

Comment: In fact, there's perhaps one more annoying technical problem, since functions such as $f(x,y)=1/x$ near $(0,0)$ are in the space, but are not locally integrable, so don't have a FT in an obvious way. This is embarrassing since we got them as FTs.

Comment: Ok, from what I am gathering, it's not clearly a well-known space. I wanted to make sure it wasn't secretly a Sobolev space of some kind. In the case of $n =1$, it is the homogeneous Sobolev space, but otherwise it doesn't seem to be the case. The space seems somewhat flexible since you can take any non-zero $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ but it also seems to be quite large.

Comment: @daniel1618. My bad--I was thinking about the constant functions but these aren't in the Schwartz space.  Sorry.  I still think it might be a good idea to consider the sum (or the $\ell^2$ sum of the $L^2$ norm and your one.  But that depends on what you are after.